# Go deserialization when type is not known

Tags: go, serialization

I'm writing a package in go to send messages between services, using a specific type of transport.

I'd like the package to not understand the type of messages being sent.
My first thought is to serialize the message object into json, send that, deserialize on the receiving end, and pass the go object (as an `interface{}`) to the subscribing code.

The serialization isn't a problem, but I don't see how the generic package code can deserialize the message since it doesn't know the type. I thought of using reflect `TypeOf()`, and passing that value as part of the message. But I don't see how to accomplish this since Type is an interface and the implementing rtype is not exported.

If the receiving app gets an `interface{}`, it is going to have to check the type anyways, so maybe it should just do the deserialization. Or the receiver could provide a reflect Type so the package can deserialize?

Or it could give the receiver a map of field name to value, but I'd prefer the actual type.

Any suggestions?

Let me add an example:

I have a go channel for sending change notifications of different types of objects. Since go doesn't support tagged unions, I define the channel type as:

```
type UpdateInfo struct {
    UpdateType UpdateType
    OldObject interface{}
    NewObject interface{}
}
```

The receiving end of the channel gets an UpdateInfo with OldObject and NewObject as the actual concrete object types that were sent.

I want to extend this to work between applications, where the transport will be via a message queue to support pub/sub, multiple consumers, etc.

Comment: The question doesn't make sense. You want to other side to not know the type but you want them to also know it? The only thing approximating this is send a json-like object (e.g. `map[string]interface{}`) but what's the point?

Comment: If the actual type is important (i.e a struct, for example), then the receiving end _must_ know it in advance, as Go cannot dynamically create custom types at runtime.

Comment: @user10753492 The sending side of my message passing package knows the concrete type. I want it to pass this info to the receiving side of the package so that it can unmarshal it into the correct concrete type.

Comment: I posted an answer assuming there's a finite set of concrete types that both sender and receiver are aware of

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### TL;DR

Just use `json.Unmarshal`.  You can wrap it lightly, using your transport, and call `json.Unmarshal` (or with a `json.Decoder` instance, use `d.Decode`) on your prebuilt JSON bytes and the `v interface{}` argument from your caller.

#### Somewhat longer, with an example

Consider how [`json.Unmarshal`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Unmarshal) does its own magic.  Its first argument is the JSON (`data []byte`), but its second argument is of type `interface{}`:

```golang
func Unmarshal(data []byte, v interface{}) error
```

As the documentation goes on to say, if `v` really *is* just an `interface{}`:

> To unmarshal JSON into an interface value, Unmarshal stores one of these in the interface value:
>
> ```golang
> bool, for JSON booleans
> float64, for JSON numbers
> string, for JSON strings
> []interface{}, for JSON arrays
> map[string]interface{}, for JSON objects
> nil for JSON null
> ```

but if `v` has an underlying *concrete type*, such as `type myData struct { ... }`, it's much fancier.  It only does the above if `v`'s underlying type *is* `interface{}`.

Its [actual implementation](https://golang.org/src/encoding/json/decode.go?s=4043:4091#L85) is particularly complex because it's optimized to do the de-JSON-ification and the assignment into the target object at the same time.  In principle, though, it's mostly a big type-switch on the underlying (concrete) type of the interface value.

Meanwhile, what you are describing in your question is that you will first deserialize into generic JSON—which really means a variable of type `interface{}`—and then do your own assignment *out* of this pre-decoded JSON into another variable of type `interface{}`, where the type signature of your own decoder would be:

```golang
func xxxDecoder(/* maybe some args here, */ v interface{}) error {
    var predecoded interface{}

    // get some json bytes from somewhere into variable `data`
    err := json.Unmarshal(data, &predecoded)

    // now emulate json.Unmarshal by getting field names and assigning
    ... this is the hard part ...
}
```

and you would then *call* this code by writing:

```golang
type myData struct {
    Field1 int    `xxx:"Field1"`
    Field2 string `xxx:"Field2"`
}
```

so that you know that JSON object key "Field1" should fill in your Field1 field with an integer, and JSON object key "Field2" should fill in your Field2 field with a string:

```golang
func whatever() {
    var x myData
    err := xxxDecode(..., &x)
    if err != nil { ... handle error ... }
    ... use x.Field1 and x.Field2 ...
}
```

But this is silly.  You can just write:

```golang
type myData struct {
    Field1 int    `json:"Field1"`
    Field2 string `json:"Field2"`
}
```

(or even omit the tags since the field's names are the default json tags), and then do this:

```golang
func xxxDecode(..., v interface{}) error {
    ... get data bytes as before ...
    return json.Unmarshal(data, v)
}
```

In other words, **just let `json.Unmarshal` do all the work** by providing *json* tags in the data structures in question.  You still get—and transmit across your special transport—the JSON data bytes *from* `json.Marshal` and `json.Unmarshal`.  You do the transmitting and receiving.  `json.Marshal` and `json.Unmarshal` do all the hard work: you don't have to touch it!

#### It's still fun to see how `Json.Unmarshal` works

Jump down to [around line 660 of `encoding/json/decode.go`](https://golang.org/src/encoding/json/decode.go#L661), where you will find the thing that handles a JSON "object" (`{` followed by either `}` or a string that represents a key), for instance:

```golang
func (d *decodeState) object(v reflect.Value) error {
```

There are some mechanics to handle corner cases (including the fact that `v` might not be settable and/or might be a pointer that should be followed), then it makes sure that `v` is either a `map[T1]T2` or `struct`, and if it is a map, that it's suitable—that both `T1` and `T2` will work when decoding the "key":value items in the object.

If all goes well, it gets into the JSON key-and-value scanning loop starting at line 720 (`for {`, which will break or return as appropriate).  On each trip through this loop, the code reads the JSON key first, leaving the `:` and value part for later.

If we're decoding into a `struct`, the decoder now uses the struct's fields—names and `json:"..."` tags—to find a `reflect.Value` that we'll use to store right into the field.<sup>1</sup>  This is `subv`, found by calling `v.Field(i)` for the right `i`, with some slightly complicated goo to handle embedded anonymous `structs` and pointer-following.  The core of this is just `subv = v.Field(i)`, though, where `i` is whichever field this key names, within the struct.  So `subv` is now a `reflect.Value` that represents the actual struct instance's value, which we should set once we've decoded the value part of the JSON key-value pair.

If we're decoding into a map, we will decode the value into a temporary first, then store it into the map after decoding.  It would be nice to share this with the struct-field storing, but we need a different `reflect` function to do the store into the map: [`v.SetMapIndex`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Value.SetMapIndex), where `v` is the `reflect.Value` of the map.  That's why for a map, `subv` points to a temporary `Elem`.

We're now ready to convert the actual value to the target type, so we go back to the JSON bytes and consume the colon `:` character and read the JSON value.  We get the value and store it into our storage location (`subv`).  This is the code starting at line 809 (`if destring {`).  The actual assigning is done through the decoder functions (`d.literalStore` at line 908, or `d.value` at line 412) and these actually decode the JSON value while doing the storing.  Note that only `d.literalStore` really stores the value—`d.value` calls on `d.array`, `d.object`, or `d.literalStore` to do the work recursively if needed.

`d.literalStore` therefore contains many `switch v.Kind()`s: it parses a `null` or a `true` or `false` or an integer or a string or an array, then makes sure it can store the resulting value into `v.Kind()`, and chooses *how* to store that resulting value into `v.Kind()` based on the combination of what it just decoded, and the actual `v.Kind()`.  So there's a bit of a combinatorial explosion here, but it gets the job done.

If all that worked, and we're decoding to a map, we may now need to massage the type of the temporary, find the real key, and store the converted value into the map.  That's what lines 830 (`if v.Kind() == reflect.Map {`) through the final close brace at 867 are about.

---

<sup>1</sup>To find fields, we first look over at `encoding/json/encode.go` to find `cachedTypeFields`.  It is a caching version of [`typeFields`](https://golang.org/src/encoding/json/encode.go#L1074).  This is where the json tags are found and put into a slice.  The result is cached via `cachedTypeFields` in a map indexed by the reflect-type value of the `struct` type.  So what we get is a slow lookup the first time we use a `struct` type, then a fast lookup afterwards, to get a slice of information about how to do the decoding.  This slice-of-information maps from json-tag-or-field name to: field; type; whether it's a sub-field of an anonymous structure; and so on: everything we will need to know to decode it properly—or to encode it, on the encoding side.  (I didn't really look closely at this code.)

Comment: What you are basically saying is that my message passing package should not attempt to unmarshal the actual message object, and leave that for the receiving app. This isn't the end of the world, but it is leaving more work for the receiving app, and exposes the fact that the message passing package is using json in its implementation.

Comment: That's not what it's saying at all. The package can handle the unmarshalling. The receiving app just passes the object it wants the message unmarshalled into, the same way you do with `json.Unmarshal`.

Comment: I wasn't clear enough in my original description, so I updated it. In my main use case (change notifications) the object contains interface{} fields, so specifying the object isn't sufficient.

Comment: If the object contains `interface{}`, the concrete type of the receiving object is `interface{}`. The cure for that is "don't do that" - receive into the actual object instead. I do think it might be handy to have a variant of `json.Unmarshal` that takes JSON-ified data as stored in `interface{}` or `map[string]interface{}` or similar, though, to avoid an extra round-trip in some cases.

Comment: My conclusion is that getting this to be as neat as a go channel isn't possible, and I should use another approach.

Answer (score 0):

You can encode/decode several message on the same buffer, whether that be a "gob" or "json" or some other encoding.

Assuming there's a limited set of concrete types that you want to support, you can always encode a type tag as the first thing, then encode the actual object. This way the decode can decode the type tag first, and depending on its value, decide how to decode the next item.

```
// encoder side

enc := json.NewEncoder(buffer) // or gob.NewEncoder(buffer)
enc.Encode("player")
enc.Encode(playerInstance)


// decoder side

dec := json.NewDecoder(buffer) // or gob.NewDecoder(buffer)
var tag string
dec.Decode(&tag)
switch tag {
    case "player":
        var playerInstance Player
        dec.Decode(&player)
        // do something with it
    case "somethingelse":
        // decode something else
}
```

Comment: Yes, and this is pretty mucyh what I'm currently doing.
But either the generic package needs to know about the set of types so it can do the decode (which isn't desired for a general change notification service) or the user of the package needs to do the decode (and I'd prefer the package did that for it)

Answer (score 0):

Try [dynobuffers](https://github.com/untillpro/dynobuffers) instead of struct. It provides get and set by name ability for byte array. Also it is much more faster than json.