# From Java to Golang: Unmarshaling Polymorphic JSON

Tags: json, go

Newbie golang programmer here. I'm working on rewriting a java application in go. The java application uses an object model that leverages Jackson's [Polymorphic Typing](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-docs/wiki/JacksonPolymorphicDeserialization) Feature to handle marshal/unmarshal to/from JSON. Assume that I can't change the shape of the JSON objects.

Given that go's offering for polymorphism is interface{}, it has been challenging to come up with an "object model" that affords the same usage patterns as far as polymorphism is concerned.

My first attempt at solving looked something like this:

```
type Thing struct {
    ID   string `json:"id"`
    Type string `json:"@type"`
}

type SpecificThing struct {
    Thing
    SpecificField string `json:"specificField"`
}

type AnotherSpecificThing struct {
    Thing
    AnotherSpecificField string `json:"anotherSpecificField"`
}
```

but that requires passing concrete subtype instances to the unmarshal method.

I've attempted to solve this by creating "Union Structs" as the vehicle for the marshal and unmarshal:

```
type Thing struct {
    ID      string      `json:"id"`
    Type    string      `json:"@type"`
    Payload interface{} `json:"-"`
}

type SpecificThing struct {
    SpecificField string `json:"specificField"`
}

type AnotherSpecificThing struct {
    AnotherSpecificField string `json:"anotherSpecificField"`
}

type superThing struct {
    ID   string `json:"id"`
    Type string `json:"@type"`
    *SpecificThing
    *AnotherSpecificThing
}

func (t *Thing) UnmarshalJSON(b []byte) error {
    //error checking omitted for brevity
    var st superThing

    _ = json.Unmarshal(b, &st)

    t.ID = st.ID
    t.Type = st.Type

    switch t.Type {
    case "specificThing":
        t.Payload = st.SpecificThing
    case "anotherSpecificThing":
        t.Payload = st.AnotherSpecificThing
    }
    return nil
}

func TestUnmarshal(t *testing.T) {
    data := []byte(`
    {
        "id":"some id",
        "@type":"specificThing",
        "specificField": "some specific field value"
    }   
    `)

    var th Thing
    _ = json.Unmarshal(data, &th)
}
```

Which works fine, as far as being able to marshal and unmarshal as far as this dynamic JSON is concerned. The downside, is that consumers of the model need to do type assertions on the Payload to interact with the subtypes to do any real work. Ideally, Is there a solution that would allow passing around "Thing" level of abstraction that would also allow for interacting with the subtypes when required? Based on reading, interfaces could be used for such a scenario, but I'm struggling to see how this model would take advantage of them. Thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that making Thing an interface and implement UnmarshalJSON this will pretty much give you what you need (users will still have to use a type asssertion/switch if they need functionality not offered by the interface but that's pretty much unavoidable). This would look something like the following:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    data := []byte(`
    {
        "id":"some id",
        "@type":"specificThing",
        "specificField": "some specific field value"
    }   
    `)

    var th ThingHolder 
    err := json.Unmarshal(data, &th)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    mySpecThing := th.T.(*SpecificThing )
    fmt.Printf("%v", mySpecThing)
}

type Thing interface {
    ID() string
}

type ThingHolder struct {
    T Thing
}

type SpecificThing struct {
    Id            string `json:"id"`
    Type          string `json:"@type"`
    SpecificField string `json:"specificField"`
}

func (s *SpecificThing) ID() string {
    return s.Id
}

func (t *ThingHolder) UnmarshalJSON(b []byte) error {
    var objMap map[string]*json.RawMessage
    err := json.Unmarshal(b, &objMap)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    // Now lets see what 'things' the JSON contains
    // by looking at JSON keys
    jsonType, ok := objMap["@type"]
    if !ok {
        return fmt.Errorf("No Type")
    }
    var goType string
    err = json.Unmarshal(*jsonType, &goType)
    if err != nil {
    return fmt.Errorf("error getting type: %s", err)
    }   

    switch goType {
    case "specificThing":
    var st SpecificThing
        err = json.Unmarshal(b, &st)
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }
        t.T = &st
    default:
    return fmt.Errorf("Unknown type %s", goType )
    }

    return nil
}
```

This approach is covered in detail on [Greg TrowBridge's blog](http://gregtrowbridge.com/golang-json-serialization-with-interfaces/).

- Updated after OP pointed out that there was a test case I had missed. Code now tested & works OK.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. See the test func in OP for example json coming in that would be a SpecificThing. As far as I understand, receiver of (t *Thing) wouldn't be allowed on an interface. I tried the same in the ide now and got a compiler error as well: "invalid receiver *Thing (pointer or interface type)"

Comment: Apologies - neglected to scroll down and missed your test function. Will update this code to include this (using a concrete type for the unmarshal)

Comment: Hopefully that's better (have tested it with your test case now).

Comment: Looks good here. It will solve the usability problems with my approach. I hadn't considered attaching the custom unmarshal at a level higher than the struct being unmarshaled. Type checking is unavoidable on Thing, but it was also unavoidable in the Java based approach where we needed to use instanceof. Marking this one accepted. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Note that this does unmarshal all the JSON bytes twice, and the "@Type" field three times. This is what I was alluding to in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59062330/go-deserialization-when-type-is-not-known#comment104389761_59065905). However, unmarshaling into `map[string]*json.RawMessage` is at least lighter-weight than other unmarshal ops.

Comment: thanks Torek; I've not seen an easy solution to that. I guess that could be an issue if dealing with large JSON files but suspect that addressing it would make the code significantly more complex (you could probably identify the type with a regex).